# change stoploss=low when I get higher high

Tags: pine-script

'var lastHigh=0.00'
'var lastLow=0.00'

after start trade I'm looking for next high>lastHigh and then the lastHigh=high the new one,
and lastLow=low the new one

`if high > lastHigh`
'lastHigh=high'
`lastLow=low`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script plots the high and low changes during the session:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
var h  = high
var l  = low
newSession = time("D") != time("D")[1]
if newSession
    h :=high
    l:=low
if high>h
    h:=high
if l>low
    l:=low
plot(h, color = color.green)
plot(l, color = color.red)
```